# awk - piping string to external gfortran-built executable in unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, pipe

I have the following awk-script "create_grid.awk" which pipes a command through to an external  exe (iri_win.exe/iri_unix.exe built with gfortran) and reads back the response via getline (creating a grid of values with two nested for-loops). Whereas everything works like a charm in windows the matter in the unix environment goes wrong.

```
!/bin/awk -f 
BEGIN {

       is_windows = 0;
       if (index(tolower(ENVIRON["OS"]), "windows") > 0) {
        is_windows = 1;
      }

      exit 
}


 {

 }

 END {

mystring=""
#myvar=""
#CMD = "cmdline | getline myvar"
#print "" > "iri_fortran_output_grid.txt"



for (j = -9 ; j <= -9; j+=2){

    for (i = -2; i <= 2; i++){

        pipe= "\"" j "," i ",0.300\n2017,823,0,12.750\n20200" "\""

        #pipe= "\"49,12,0.300\n2017,823,1,12.750\n20200 \""
        #pipe= "\"49,12,0.300\n2017,823,1,12.750\n20200\""

        if (is_windows)
            cmdline = "echo -e " pipe " | ./iri_win.exe"
        else
            cmdline = "echo -e " pipe " | ./iri_unix.exe"

        print cmdline


        if ( (cmdline | getline myvar) > 0 ) {

            #close(cmdline | getline myvar)
            print "latitude " j " , longitude " i " done, TEC: " myvar " ;" 

        }
        else{
            #close(cmdline | getline myvar)
            print "error in latitude " j " , longitude " i
        }

        close(cmdline)
        #close(getline)

        #cmdline | getline myvar
        #myvar = $0

        mystring = mystring  myvar " "

    }

    # print one line into result file
    sub(/[ \t]+$/, "", mystring)
    sub(/^[ \t]+/, "", mystring)
    print mystring > "iri_fortran_output_grid.txt"
    print "longitude " j " done"
    mystring=""

    fflush("iri_fortran_output_grid.txt")
    fflush(stdout)

    #close("iri_fortran_output_grid.txt")


}

}
```

**Output of awk script in Unix OS:**

```
loren32@nautilus:~/iri_exe_analysis$gawk -f ./create_grid.awk

At line 107 of file iri_4_tec_al_2.for (unit = 5, file = 'stdin')
Fortran runtime error: Bad real number in item 1 of list input
error in latitude -9 , longitude 0
echo -e "-9,1,0.300
2017,823,0,12.750
20200" | ./iri_unix.exe
...
```

**Output in Unix OS only executing external exe :**

```
loren32@nautilus:~/iri_exe_analysis$ echo -e "-9,1,0.300\n2017,823,1,12.750\n20200" | ./iri_unix.exe
18.452
```

As can be seen when I pipe my string via `echo -e "stringcontent"` to iri_unix.exe from bash in Unix it works but the call from within the awk script fails.

I suspect the quotes work differently in unix and somehow additional disturbing string data is sent to iri_unix.exe - hence the error message "Bad real number in item 1 of list input".

I wonder what is going wrong and how to correct my awk script to make it work in Unix OS. In Windows the script works fine

Comment: double quote will expand the content at shell level so try to use single quote in unix. Is it normal that you use `\n` in both windows and unix because windows usually us CR + LF (2 chars) where unix only LF

Comment: I recommend to clean up and indent your code properly before posting it  here. SO is not a pastebin

Comment: hek2mgl I would very much appreciate it If you could contribute to the matter instead of writing an Off topic recommendation on how to present Code. Just proves my opinion right that Here are too many Blockwärte around

Answer (score -1):

The workaround is to write

```
  echo "..."
```

in the Unix Environment and leave out the -e option. That die the trick for me.